# mySQL: Source file always put into database "uni" instead of desired database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a problem with mySQL while trying to source in a .sql database. I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and using mySQL through the terminal. This is my process of sourcing the database:

```
mysql -u root - p
```

Enter my password...

```
create database Courses;
```

Now my database called 'Courses' is created.

```
use database Courses;
```

Now I'm using the desired database.

```
source /path/to/file/course.sql;
```

That sources in the course.sql file I have located in a few folders within Documents. This is what it says:

```
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Database changed
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

And then a ton of these:

```
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)
```

So it appears that it automatically changes the database.
When I 'show tables;' this is what it shows:

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------+
| Tables_in_uni |
+---------------+
| COURSE        |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

It put the .sql file in database 'uni'. That's the problem. When I go to my created database called "Courses", it's empty. I can operate out of "uni" just like a regular database but it's not in the correct database and won't go in the correct database. I've also tried this method:

```
mysql -u root -p COURSES < /path/to/file/course.sql;
```

Same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The file located at `/path/to/file/course.sql` contains a line `use uni`. Remove that line and will get the behavior you are expecting.